# What is considered best practice when supplying elements to an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning java after moving over from python. The way arrays can be assigned values is a bit new to me. I can either use this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
}
```

Or:

```
int[] otherArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...};
// or this
int[] otherArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...};
```

I understand that I can use the ArrayList class to do other things, and that I can change the size with a variable that updates when the program compiles, but out of these two, which is considered best practice? Does it matter?

Comment: Those two choices so completely different things.

Comment: You seem to confuse different concepts in your question. Array and ArrayList are very different data structures in Java! List implementations do offer flexible size space, so to speak, but what you seem to ask is how to populate an Array and not an ArrayList. Also, what you demonstrated in your code examples, does show in both examples how elements could be added to Arrays, but it important to notice that second example is used for small set of known values, and if that is the case do you really need to have them in such structure?

Comment: @Tackler529 I see where I caused confusion. I should have clarified. I understand that a n ArrayList is different from an array. I should have worded it better on my end, sorry about that. I was merely referring two the two code examples I provided. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which is considered best practice? Does it matter?

First of all, beware of "best practice".  In the programming world it *almost never exists*.

- Beware of people who tell you that something is "best practice".  Treat what they say with healthy scepticism.
- Avoid asking for "best practices".  It is almost certainly the wrong question to ask.

Read and contemplate this:

- [No Best Practice](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27) by James Bach.

---

To your question.  You have presented two different ways of initializing an array, but they have different characteristics.

- The first one creates and initializes an array of numbers in increasing order, starting from one.  The size of the array is a parameter and this code will work for different sizes.
- The second one also creates and initializes an array of numbers in increasing order, starting from one.  But in this case, the size of the array is determined by the number of numbers in the initializer your source code; i.e.

  ```
  int[] otherArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};    // produces a 4 value array
  ```

  or

  ```
  int[] otherArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // produces a 5 value array
  ```

So which is better?

It depends on what you are trying to do.

- If you want an small array with always the same number of numbers, the 2nd approach is simpler and (arguably) better.
- If you want an array where there isn't a simple algorithm to generate the values, then the 1st approach (which relies on a simple algorithm) doesn't work.
- If you want to initialize a large array (say hundreds of elements), the 2nd approach is cumbersome.
- If `size` needs to vary, clearly the 2nd approach doesn't work.

---

Is there a "best practice" here?

Clearly, No.  Different problems *require* different approaches.  A one-size-fits-all "best practice" would not work, let alone be the best solution for all problems.

And this reasoning applies to *the vast majority* of "best practice" questions in programming.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer I have received about programming thus far. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that either is fine in the situation that you need it. If you know the size, and are sure the bounds are correct, the first one works fine. The second one can only be done if you already know the values of each element of your array at creation time.

The accepted answer does a better job speaking to the philosophy of such a question.